# sproxy for vs2008?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2008, wcf, wcf-client

I'm trying to create WCF proxy in unmanaged C++ (No .NET framework is installed on the client).

I've found the website "http://icoder.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/consuming-a-wcf-service-with-an-unmanaged-c-client-with-credential-passing/" which teaches how to generate such a proxy.

The problem is that I've found the sproxy.exe only in VS 2003, and not in 2008.

When I'm creating proxy with this VS 2003 tool, I can compile it with VS 2003, but when I'm trying to compile the generated file using VS 2008, it gets the error: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlsoap.h': No such file or directory".

What can I do?

Thanks,

Mattan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATL Server was (re)moved from ATL in Visual Studio 2008 to [codeplex](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/), where it has found its resting place.

Can you use Visual Studio 2005?

Alternatives?

- [GSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), requires a license for commercial development
- [Qt SOAP](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap/), is a partial implementation of SOAP v1.1
- [Windows Web Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435%28VS.85%29.aspx), works only on Windows 7

Comment: What is protocol 1.1? of what?

Comment: I've downloaded the ATLServer from codeplex and now its ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the other solution is to create a managed proxy with [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx), and use C++\CLI to communicate between native C++ and the managed proxy.

This solution works with all wcf bindings.